# Red5 Recorder under FB 4.5

Tags: flash, apache-flex, webcam, video-capture, red5

I've downloaded a copy of FlashBuilder 4.5 and the latest of Red5-recorder (from http://www.red5-recorder.com/) - at first I had a bunch of errors as apparently the latest version of FB uses a different them than what the project expects (Halo).  I changed it and it was better but the app doesn't work as expected.

at present my problem is that there is a Rec(ord) button which doesn't show up once the app runs.  I've looked at the properties (it's inside an mx:Canvas) and everything looks ok.  I've spent some time looking at the initialisation code but I can't figure out what the issue could be.

I'm not a Flex guy and am just hoping for a simple solution to my video-capture problem.  Has anyone used this combination of products with any success.  alternatively, could anyone suggest how I can troubleshoot this?

thanks - e

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the server to which the player is connection for recording is configured correctly and accessible. The Record button will only show if the recorder (can be oflademo recorder setup locally/ the any other recorder are setup correctly and accessible). Hope that helps.